# Windows GUI app with Docker Container running Python code in background

Tags: windows, docker

I made a Java application in the past for Windows which performs some scientific analysis. This scientific analysis was done by executing a Python script in a Docker container because it required dependencies that were hard to install on Windows.

The GUI application uses Powershell to launch Docker Toolbox in the background which is then used to execute the Python script. My application then waits for the results by checking for the output file's existence.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this (develop a Windows application that uses Docker containers to run certain code). Any suggestions for technologies that I may consider is appreciated.

**TLDR**: What's the best way to develop a Windows GUI application that requires some background processing with Docker container?